# hide div that is after another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of `<div class="clear-both"></div>` after a series of divs.

I want to remove any `<div class="clear-both"></div>` that displays after where that checkbox appears.

For example,

```
<input type="checkbox" value="male"> Male?

<div class="clear-both"></div>
```

If the user checks the box, I want the `<div class="clear-both"></div>` right below it to disappear.

There is about a dozen instances of the clear-both div's on the page.

I assume I'll have to set a class for each checkbox, to listen for when the user checks the box, but I am unsure on how I can remove the clear-both div below the checkbox.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('div.clear-both').hide();
}):
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove any  that displays
>   after where that checkbox appears.

You can use `next()` like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
   $(this).next('div.clear-both').remove();
});
```

This will remove the next `div` element of the clicked checkbox whichever is clicked.

**More:**

http://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 1):

While this is easily do-able with jQuery/JavaScript, you also don't *need* to use JavaScript; CSS can be used instead (depending on your cross-browser requirements):

```
.clear-both {
    height: 1em;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

input:checked + .clear-both {
    background-color: #00f;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fySkx/).

Note, I used color-changing simply because I was unsure of which state you wanted the `.clear-both` to be visible/hidden. Obviously, adjust the style to your needs.

To further clarify the limitations of this approach, in terms of cross-browser compatibility, according to [Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-checked) this is not supported by any version of Internet Explorer (though they only list IE up to version 8).

However [Quirksmode clarifies that IE 9+](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t33) do/es support the `:checked` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use jQuery:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
     var element = elements[i];
     if(element.type == "checkbox")
        element.onchange = function() { this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none"; };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the suggestions to use the `next` function will only work for one div below. You said you wanted to remove all of them so you should look at the `nextAll` function:

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/